# How are the concepts redemption and salvation related in Judaism?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, words

Does the term salvation (or save, yeshua) encompass redemption (geula)?  Does redemption concern harm or punishment has already occurred while salvation contemplates future possible future harm?  Does forgiveness apply only to redemption?  Or are the terms redemption and salvation basically interchangeable in Hebrew and English translation?

Comment: I know its long, but here is a helpful link: 
https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?filename=23&article=1066&context=mi&type=additional

Comment: Geulah is redemption from a situation; e.g. bondage. Yeshua is salvation from a misfortune: e.g. not getting hit by a car. There can definitely be overlap, if you are saved from a bad situation.

Answer (score 1):

We know that ישועת ה' כהרף עין, that got me thinking that salvation (ישועה) is used when it's an immediate salvation, one minute in distress next minute salvation. Redemption (גאולה) on the other hand is a 'process' over a period of time. A proof to that I'll bring from the Gemara Berachos 4b (from sefaria)

דְּרַבִּי יוֹחָנָן סָבַר גְּאוּלָּה מֵאוּרְתָּא נָמֵי הָוֵי, אֶלָּא גְּאוּלָּה מְעַלַּיְיתָא לָא הָוְיָא אֶלָּא עַד צַפְרָא. וְרַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן לֵוִי סָבַר כֵּיוָן דְּלָא הָוְיָא אֶלָּא מִצַּפְרָא — לָא הָוְיָא גְּאוּלָּה מְעַלַּיְיתָא.

Rabbi Yoḥanan holds: Redemption occurred in the evening as well; however, the full-fledged redemption was only in the morning. Since the redemption began in the evening, it is appropriate to juxtapose the blessing of redemption to the daily evening prayer. Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi, on the other hand, holds: Since full-fledged redemption only occurred in the morning, and the redemption of the previous evening was not a full-fledged redemption, there is no need to juxtapose the blessing of redemption to the evening prayer.

Clearly Geuala can be a process till finally an ultimate redemption.

Comment: What about the root of the words, and usage in Tanach, lends to this explanation?

Comment: Nice explanation shayachagigah,! I would have the same question as Rabbi Kaii, that we need more sources other than the Gemera in Brachot to prove that this is really true for most other areas